# nslookup resolves to old IP address

Tags: windows, azure

I have an azure windows VM which was recently moved to another subnet. Hence new IP address was assigned to that VM. I have an issue now that the nslookup results still points to the old IP address.

```
C:\Users\xx>nslookup hostname.domainname
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.xx.xx.xx

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    hostname.domainname
Address:  <old IP address>
```

How to resolve this

Comment: So what have you done so far to investigate this? How is your DNS setup, have you updated the record in DNS?

Answer (score 0):

> How to resolve this

Update your DNS record.

Either manually or from the VM itself by typing `ipconfig /registerdns` (as long as the DNS zone allows dynamic updates).